# Can i create custom objects that i can animate using vpython? should i use another library?

Tags: python

i want to make a model that will rotate about the x,y and z axis. ive been looking at [vpython](http://vpython.org/contents/overview.html)'s available 3d objects but i dont think that i any of them will suit my application. im looking to animate a car, or at least something that resembles it. if anyone has experienced making one or know a similar python library where i can create/animate 3d objects please let me know. thank you for your help

Comment: Did you mean `_w_xPython` instead?

Comment: um no sir its actually vpython. http://vpython.org/contents/doc.html

Comment: I hit that same limit pretty quickly with vPython's builtin shapes, I don't see they make it possible to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make an object which is a composite of primitives and treat it as a single part.  See visual.frame in the documentation.